# Commerce price per thousand

Tags: commerce

I use [Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce). I have some products whose price is "per thousand". For example, I sell screws. The price for one thousand is 10$. I want to show 10$ as product price in web, but I want the seller could set quantity in thousands. Then, the seller put, for example, 2500, and the total line should be 25$. But I see: unit price 10$, quantity 2500, total line 25$.

I don't want to alter the unit price because I'll lost precision. I need to alter the way the total line is calculated, and if a product is of this kind, the total line will be divided by 1000.
I've tried to do it with rules, but I couldn't do it because I can't alter total line.
Thanks in advance.

UPDATED:
After some test, finally I use [Commerce decimal quantities](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_decimal_quantities) module. I add a rule to divide by 1000 the quantity selected by the user. Then, internally I have decimal quantities that give me the right price. I also change the cart's views to show the quantity multiply by 1000. Hope can help for someone who need it. Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked out the contribution modules for Commerce that have additional rules?

Comment: Yes. I did it. But the most of them are for discount or for alter product price. I need to alter total line.